# Change Rmarkdown html fonts on specific language

Tags: css, r, knitr, r-markdown

I use two languages in Rmarkdown : Korean, and English
and I want to change the Korean fonts.

This is Rmd file.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  html_document:
    highlight: kate
    theme: cosmo
    css: styles.css
---
```

This is styles.css file

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/nanumgothic.css); 
html{
font-family: Arial,'Nanum Gothic', sans-serif;
}
```

But this css file does not work well :(

Comment: You could set each block separately by wrapping them in `htmltools::tags$div` with a style attribute (or a class if you want to use external CSS) in code chunks or just actual HTML in the text portions. If you're switching back and forth a lot, that may get really finicky, though, so hopefully there's a better alternative.